# When I am deploying by ASP.NET MVC application on IIS I am specifying my credentials in Identity as a setting in DefaultAppPool

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, active-directory, usergroups

Also if i don't give my credentials it gives some configuration file error.

I want AD authentication to take place. But it always picks my username when logged from different systems. How do I resolve it?

Is there any way I can make a user group and assign that to the Identity in DefaultAppPool or do I need to change the code for authentication as it is only taking the user from the Identity mentioned in DefaultAppPool?

The code that I am using to validate the user who logs in is as follows:

```
string groupName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["groupName"].ToString();
string domainName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"].ToString();
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,IdentityType.SamAccountName,System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
if (user != null)
{ //code as required }
```

code in web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="domain" value="EYDEV" />
  <add key="groupName" value="Domain Users" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` gets the credentials that your application is running under, not the current user.

You need to first enable Windows Authentication by adding this to your `system.web` section of your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

See Microsoft's documentation for more details (like making sure you have the right IIS features installed): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs

Once that is setup, you can use `User.Identity.Name` in a Controller to get the username of the current user.

Comment: Ok. But here again I am facing the issue that I want the login name for the user and not the display name. And hence I was using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name Can you please suggest the alternative for that so that i can get the login name (eg. domain\name) for the current user.

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` has the domain\username

Comment: when i am using User.Identity.Name it is returning blank. what may be the possible issue?

Comment: Windows Authentication isn't happening. Go through the steps on the Microsoft page I linked to to make sure Windows Authentication is enabled.